# XNA 3.1 DrawUserPrimitives with Anti Aliasing - MultiSampling doesn't work?

Tags: c#, xna, antialiasing, multisampling

So this is a continuation of a question I asked earlier today. I've built myself some nice looking ribbon trails using XNA 3.1's DrawUserPrimitives method, essentially by expanding a polygon as motion occurs. It all looks super sleek and nice, except for one thing - anti-aliasing. I cannot for the life of me work out how to apply it.

I've set this in the game constructor:

```
graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
```

And I've also added this to test for the hardware:

```
        graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>((sender, e) =>
        {
            PresentationParameters parameters = e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters;
            parameters.MultiSampleQuality = 0;

        #if XBOX
                pp.MultiSampleType = MultiSampleType.FourSamples;
                return;
        #else

            int quality;
            GraphicsAdapter adapter = e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.Adapter;
            SurfaceFormat format = adapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Format;

            if (adapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType(DeviceType.Hardware, format, false, MultiSampleType.FourSamples, out quality))
            {
                parameters.MultiSampleType = MultiSampleType.FourSamples;
            }
            else if (adapter.CheckDeviceMultiSampleType(DeviceType.Hardware, format, false, MultiSampleType.TwoSamples, out quality))
            {
                parameters.MultiSampleType = MultiSampleType.TwoSamples;
            }
        #endif
        });
```

By adding some print lines, I know my hardware can support 4 sample AA, but this all seems to make no difference. I just can't seem to get this to work.

Here's a screenshot of one of my trails with all of that code applied:

[image: See? No AA!]

I'd really appreciate some help. I looked at this a while ago for a solution to a different problem, and couldn't get it to work then, either.

Well, cheers.

Comment: Are this really polygons? Or are you rendering polygons and applying a texture which looks aliased? Because multisampling only makes the lines of polygons smooth, nothing more. If you using textures and rotating them to get the trail effect, you might see the aliasing that comes from transforming and mapping the texture, which can't be avoided with multisampling. Just want to make sure.

Comment: No, I'm drawing polygon vertices and mapping colours to them in order to follow the direction of motion more accurately, and keep the correct transparency. No textures are mapped to draw the trail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed this one, too!

The issue was that, while the back buffer was getting the right anti-alias settings, the render target wasn't. This meant that drawing to the render target was done without AA, but the texture that was then drawn to the back buffer was done with it. I've fixed it now.